# Error Exception using seed

Tags: laravel, seed

i have database contains some table ..one of them (thsises Table) .. i tried to seed some fake data .. but when i run 
    php artisan db:seed
it throws an SQL Error ... and this is my factory for this table :

```
$factory->define(App\Thesise::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {

return [
    'program_id' =>$faker->numberBetween($min = 1, $max = 5),
    'ar_title' =>$faker->sentences,
    'en_title' =>$faker->sentences,
    'student_id' =>$faker->numberBetween($min = 3, $max = 20),
    'ar_brief' =>$faker->sentences,
    'en_brief' =>$faker->sentences,
    'ar_expalin' =>$faker->text,
    'en_explain' =>$faker->text,
    'date' =>$faker->date($format = '2000-01-01', $max = 'now'),
    'primary_siminar' =>$faker->date($format = '2000-01-01', $max = 'now'),
    'final_siminar' =>$faker->date($format = '2000-01-01', $max = 'now'),
    'test_date' =>$faker->date($format = '2000-01-01', $max = 'now'),
    'degree_date' =>$faker->date($format = '2000-01-01', $max = 'now'),
    'degree' =>$faker->randomFloat($nbMaxDecimals = 2, $min = 60, $max = 100), // 48.8932
    'degreey' =>$faker->sentences,
    'mat_avg' =>$faker->randomFloat($nbMaxDecimals = 2, $min = 60, $max = 100), // 48.8932
    'final_degree' =>$faker->randomFloat($nbMaxDecimals = 2, $min = 60, $max = 100), // 48.8932
    'f_ad' =>$faker->numberBetween($min = 1, $max = 10),
    'f_a' =>$faker->numberBetween($min = 1, $max = 10),
    'j_ad' =>$faker->numberBetween($min = 1, $max = 10),
    'j1' =>$faker->numberBetween($min = 1, $max = 10),
    'j2' =>$faker->numberBetween($min = 1, $max = 10),
    'file' =>$faker->sentences,
];
```

});

and this is my up function for migration table

```
   public function up()
{
    Schema::create('thesises', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('program_id');
        $table->string('ar_title');
        $table->string('en_title');
        $table->integer('student_id')->unsigned();
        $table->text('ar_brief');
        $table->text('en_brief');
        $table->longText('ar_expalin');
        $table->longText('en_explain');
        $table->date('date');
        $table->date('primary_siminar');
        $table->date('final_siminar');
        $table->date('test_date');
        $table->date('degree_date');
        $table->double('degree');
        $table->string('degreey');
        $table->double('mat_avg');
        $table->double('final_degree');
        $table->integer('f_ad');
        $table->integer('f_a');
        $table->integer('j_ad');
        $table->integer('j1');
        $table->integer('j2');
        $table->string('file');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

ThesisesTabelSeeder like this :

```
class ThesisesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
    factory(\App\Thesise::class , 10)->create();
}
```

}

and i call it as :

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
     $this->call(ThesisesTableSeeder::class);
}
```

}

when i seed .. it throws error exception (array to string conversion ) ...any help please !!

Comment: Show me where and how are you calling your factory.

Comment: i call it form DatabaseSeeder

Comment: public function run()
    {
         $this->call(ThesisesTableSeeder::class);
    }

Comment: and the ThesisesTableSeeder is .....  public function run()
    {
        factory(\App\Thesise::class , 10)->create();
    }
}

Comment: Can you add this lines of code in your question, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `Faker\Generator` class, the method/property `sentences` returns an array of strings.

> - @property string $sentence
> - @method string sentence($nbWords = 6, $variableNbWords = true)
> - @property string|array $sentences
> - @method string|array sentences($nb = 3, $asText = false)

So, you should use the method/property `sentence` instead. For example:

```
$factory->define(App\Thesise::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        ...
        'ar_title' => $faker->sentence, // or.
        'en_title' => $faker->sentence(3, true),
        ...
    ];
}
```